# Difference in playing a matched AI and choosing an AI

Tags: starcraft-2

There seems to be two ways to play against AI. One is the practice against a matched AI where you choose races and based on performance the game sets the difficulty level. If you you loose to much the AI becomes lower.

Then there is custom games where you can choose your own AI.

Are these the same AIs? Will they use the same algorithms based on their level? 
Also, do the more difficult AIs cheat?

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by cheat?

Comment: Anything players don’t have access too. Like higher damage, enemy info without seeing it,more income for the same work etc...

Comment: Also clarify what you mean by custom. Do you mean custom as in the arcade or do you mean custom as in choosing a specific map and AI opponents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AI's are always the same, unless you are playing in the Arcade where people can mess with the AI scripts.

There are many algorithms that AI can use based on level, not all opponents will play the same, even if they are the same difficulty. For example, one Terran opponent might go heavier bio and one might go heavier mech builds.

No, the AI does not cheat, they can not mine more minerals or build faster than you can, for example. The only thing they can do that might be considered cheating is control multiple units at nearly the same time.

Comment: The higher difficulty AIs after Brutal are called "Cheater", with different types of cheating. Some have full map view, others receive more resources, etc. Those advertise it in their name, so I'm not entirely sure why you say that the AI does not cheat.